# error: cannot initialize return object of type 'const char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [34]'

Tags: c++

I am a new to g++.

I am trying to compile this simple code.

However, has this error.

error: cannot initialize return object of type 'const char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [34]'

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const doYouDo( const char* jobs ){
    return "Hello, I am an embedded engineer.";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( what ){
    boost::python::def( "doYouDo", doYouDo);
}
```

Where should I fix?

My g++ compile command is here.

```
$g++ -fPIC -Wall -I/System/Volumes/Data/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/aiwave/include/python3.6m/ -lboost_python -shared -o whatModule.so what.cpp
```

Comment: It looks like your return type should be `char const *` instead  of `char const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"Hello, I am an embedded engineer."
```

... is a [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), it has a type of `const char[]` and your function is defined to return a single constant character (`char const`), hence your error.

What you can do:

Since you can't return C-style arrays by value in C++, you can return a pointer instead:

```
char const* doYouDo( const char* jobs ) {
    return "Hello, I am an embedded engineer.";
}
```

Or you can also use `std::string` since it has a built-in constructor from `const char*`:

```
std::string doYouDo( const char* jobs ) {
    return "Hello, I am an embedded engineer.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* const doYouDo( const char* jobs ) {
    return "Hello, I am an embedded engineer.";
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't useful.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).